# Generic proxy objects deleted

Tags: proxy, abap

During the implementation of [SAP note 2724847](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2724847), some generic proxy objects are deleted:

[image: So this are the missing objects they are inactive because they are non existent]

I don't know what was the code they contained is there any way I could get them back or where I can find its code ?

I don't have much experience with proxy objects and don't fully understand the problem but apparently someone else deleted some ABAP views and the errors appeared.

I already checked the notes and I couldn't find the code inside the objects.

Here are the changes the note is supposed to do and the note is apparently successfully implemented:

[image]

And here are the changes better explained by the note :

[image]

Comment: The image does not have it that they are inactive rather than they were deleted. Just activate the stuff.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, i tried activating them but i get the message "Could not create WB object from  (type)  (name) (encl.) " anything i can do there?

Comment: Those objects in the namespace `/TMF/` do not look like SAP standard objects, especially when I see some portugese naming there. Therefore I do not think it has something to do with the SAP note implementation either. Could you post screenshots of what exactly you are doing till the error message comes?

Comment: id like to but i am not the one that was doing the implementation i was handed down this error but there is a note numberd 2724847 and it does implement those objects

Comment: i was told the notes were automatic and the error apeared in a note that when i investigated it it had nothing to do with it

Comment: OK, I see that the note is relevant only for Brasil. Has the note 2732151 been implemented as well? In the note description I see that this is a prerequisite for the note 2724847.

Comment: You cannot display the code of these objects via the SAP support website, you can only see it via the transaction code `SNOTE`. Maybe there's an issue with the note, open a ticket at the SAP support.